# useEffect doesn't update the ui after running - typescript

Tags: reactjs, typescript, use-effect, use-state

I am having problems with useEffect and conditional rendering.

Basically I have code that uses useState hook named loggedIn, and it is false by default. And I have template like this:

```
<>
  {!loggedIn && (
    <div className="buttons d-flex justify-content-between">
        <Link to="/login" className="btn btn-warning rounded-0">Login</Link>
        <Link to="/register" className="btn btn-primary rounded-0">Register</Link>
    </div>
   )}
</>
```

and useEffect looks like this:

```
const [loggedIn, setLoggedIn] = useState(false)
useEffect(()=>{
    if(localStorage.getItem("auth")) {
        setLoggedIn(true)
    } else {
        setLoggedIn(false)
    }
}, [loggedIn])
```

It doesn't hide after updating the value of loggedIn

Comment: setState is a function, it should be `setLoggedIn(true)`

Comment: It is, sorry I mistyped it

Comment: Can you show us the condition logic and triggering method?

Comment: I updated the question. But still it's the same problem. I can see that variable has changed, but nothing happens in the UI until I refresh the page

Comment: Have you checked to see if you're setting localstorage correctly?

Answer (score 0):

You probably have to pass in the loggedIn, in the dependency array, this tracks state changes.

Try this:

```
const [loggedIn, setLoggedIn] = useState(false)
useEffect(()=>{
    if(condition) {
        setLoggedIn(true)
    } else {
        setLoggedIn(false)
    }
}, [condition])
```

Comment: I tried that, it doesn't work still

Comment: Question, how are you triggering the condition ? what is the condition logic, maybe you should check the state of the ```condition```

Answer (score 0):

You don't mention what `condition` is but here is a one liner with a ternary as an option:

```js
const [loggedIn, setLoggedIn] = useState(false)
useEffect(() => condition ? setLoggedIn(true) : setLoggedIn(false), [loggedIn])
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
// In the App level component
const [authToken, setAuthToken] = useState();

useEffect(() =>{
    if (localStorage.auth) { 
      setAuthToken(localStorage.auth); // Grab token on page refresh
    }
},[]}

// Pass 'authToken' to your component below:
const [loggedIn, setLoggedIn] = useState(false)

useEffect(()=>{
    if(authToken) {
        setLoggedIn(true)
    } else {
        setLoggedIn(false)
    }
}, [authToken]) // Listen to authToken's change
```

On page load we are grabing the token from local storage, and store it in the `authToken` state, where you can listen to the it's change, and conditionally render your component.